# Shuffle.js reverse sorting with checkbox via prototype & addEventListener, partially working codepen

Tags: javascript, prototype, addeventlistener, shuffle

I added this inside **Demo.prototype._handleSortChange** to reverse the sort order if the radio is checked...

```
  var order = true;
  function reverseOrder() {
    if (document.getElementById('order').checked) {
      order = true;
    } else {          
      order = false;
    }
    console.log('reverseOrder: '+order);
  }
  reverseOrder();
```

What I can't figure out is to call the sorting function when you check or uncheck the radio input without having to re-select the sort order dropdown.

```
Demo.prototype.reverseSorting = function () {
  // this call resets the sort order to default, rather than just reversing the selected order...
  document.getElementById('order').addEventListener('click', this._handleSortChange.bind(this));
};
```

Codepen https://codepen.io/midaspider/pen/ZEBwBqw

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I was looking at the wrong section as being the problem, the solution was very simple really.

```
Demo.prototype._handleSortChange = function (event) {
  //var value = event.target.value;
  var value = document.querySelector('.sort-options').value;
```

I realised the value of the select input wasn't being passed if I clicked the checkbox, so I changed **var value** to explicitly get the value from the select input rather than get the value passed from event. Now it works, I've updated the Codepen for reference in case anyone else needs this.